# sticky header is cutting the content when i change the size of the window

Tags: html, css, menu, header, sticky

its pretty much it. i made a sticky header that cuts off the page when i adjust the size of the window to a smaller size

maybe someone can help me out on this one! thanks!

```
    html, body {

    padding-top: 40px;
    height:100%;

    }

    .page {

    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;

    }

    .content {

    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom:60px;   /* footer height */

    }

    /* sticky top */

    .topo2 {

position: fixed;
width: 100%;
background: white;
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 100;
border-top: 0;
```

the z-index atribute i have no idea what it does, i just put it there because someone told me too

Comment: You need media query for that. Check This:https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/responsive-fixed-header-with-css/

Comment: What happens when you adjust the size of the browser window? What does *cuts off the page* mean? -- `z-index` sets the stack order of elements. If two elements were on top of each other, the one with higher `z-index` would be in the "front" and the one with the lower value would be "behind".

Comment: Please paste your html code. Or if you can paste the css and html at https://jsfiddle.net/ , it will better